# Apache Nifi 1,8,0 and CryptographicHashContent

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a file and calculate the hash of the content but it never matches the same calculation in Java or using online tools to compare.
I added 'debug' level processor logging, but it doesn't help.

Per

Comment: Hi. Please share the configuration of the processor (which hash algorithm is selected), an example of input data, the output of the processor, and "expected output" (i.e. what a command-line run or Java digest looks like). Please ensure there is no trailing whitespace that could be influencing the output.

Comment: First thing tomorrow

Comment: Nifi processor config:  Hash Algorithm: SHA-256

input (no trailing whitespace):
abcdefghbcdefghicdefghijdefghijkefghijklfghijklmghijklmnhijklmno

 java output:
2ff100b36c386c65a1afc462ad53e25479bec9498ed00aa5a04de584bc25301b

web site (https://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) output:
2ff100b36c386c65a1afc462ad53e25479bec9498ed00aa5a04de584bc25301b

python hashlib output:
2ff100b36c386c65a1afc462ad53e25479bec9498ed00aa5a04de584bc25301b

nifi output:
Key: 'content_SHA-256'
Value: '69ebd9e994e5207d8e8b17b83e081b6f6da47afef2259b7c222e32d4f6d87fe8'

Comment: Formatted here: https://pastebin.com/umGLbkDJ

Answer (score 1):

The process you have described and the example values you've provided should work. I've replicated your flow and I get the expected output (`2ff...`) in NiFi for the calculated SHA-256 hash of your static input string.

I've [attached a template](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/8728c729e50f01aa451f4d1c143c7172) of my flow. Please import this to your instance of NiFi and run it to compare the results. If you get an incorrect value from this flow, there is something seriously wrong with your NiFi instance. If you get the correct value, I believe a configuration issue in the original flow is to blame.

**Update** I was able to replicate your output if there was a trailing newline character on the input you provided. You need to trim the input, or include a newline when calculating the hash with a different mechanism.

`abcdefghbcdefghicdefghijdefghijkefghijklfghijklmghijklmnhijklmno\n` -> `69ebd9e994e5207d8e8b17b83e081b6f6da47afef2259b7c222e32d4f6d87fe8`

`abcdefghbcdefghicdefghijdefghijkefghijklfghijklmghijklmnhijklmno` -> `2ff100b36c386c65a1afc462ad53e25479bec9498ed00aa5a04de584bc25301b`

Comment: Yes, the data came from S3 and I think an extra '\n' is added, so that explains it.